# Replace character in raw data before parsing to JSON using node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-fetch

I'm trying to fetch raw data from a website and convert it into JSON, but the problem is that the data uses single quotes instead of double quotes, which gives an error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at (WEBSITE_LINK) reason: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

If I open the page in my browser, this is what the data looks like:
`{'test': True, 'number': 0}`

How can I convert the single quotes to double quotes before parsing it into JSON using the following code?

```
let url = `WEBSITE_LINK`;
let settings = { method: "Get" };
fetch(url, settings)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then((json) => {
         console.log(json.test)
         console.log(json.number)
    });
```

Comment: True should also be replaced with true

Comment: The reason its not valid json is because the word - True is not valid javascript. Ask the backend provider to supply you with true, lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the js String [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method ad parse the returning sting manually.

```
let url = `WEBSITE_LINK`;
let settings = { method: "Get" };
fetch(url, settings)
   .then(res => res.text())
   .then((text) => {
         const json = JSON.parse(text.replace(/'/g, '"'));
         console.log(json.test);
         console.log(json.number);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Unfortunately, I'm receiving an error when I try to execute that code: `(node:18872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.text(...).replace is not a function` - I tried changing it to res.text().toString.replace but that didn't work either

Comment: Ah yes, res.text returns a promise. You can do the parsing in the other then call

Answer (score 0):

Use the *String* constructor to convert the response to a string and then apply the replace method.

```js
let url = `WEBSITE_LINK`;
let settings = {
  method: "Get"
};
fetch(url, settings)
  .then(res => {
    const text = String(res.text()).replace(/'/g, '"');
    return JSON.parse(text);
  })
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json.test)
    console.log(json.number)
  });
```

Comment: How would I also change "True" to "true"?

Comment: You could use the "toLowerCase()" method.